# openid with django

Tags: python, django, openid

I found a lot of options but this one https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth 
looks good. sadly I can't find examples/HOWTO about this?Does anyone point/redirect me to correct urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little howto:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~django-openid-auth/django-openid-auth/trunk/annotate/head:/README.txt

Also you have exact usage examples here:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~django-openid-auth/django-openid-auth/trunk/files/head:/example_consumer/

You could also look at this solution here - in my opinion much better documented:
http://github.com/simonw/django-openid/tree/master/django_openid/docs/

Or you could use the best avaible solution (unfortunatelly not free), provided here: https://rpxnow.com/